# How do I view 2 names in one SELECT query

Tags: sql

I want to get two user names from users table by matching them with **usrID** and **res_usrID** fields from my **cases** table to view their names from **users** table with **usrGivenName** field. I want to view them on same line. How can I do that ?

```
SELECT 
         caseID
      ,c.date_created
      ,c.date_approval_request
      ,c.date_closed
      ,u.usrGivenName 
      ,c.muh_usrID
  FROM cases AS c
  JOIN users AS u ON c.usrID=u.usrID
```

Comment: Please provide a sample how you would like the output to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a [self join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) (i.e., additional join to same table):

```
SELECT 
        c.caseID
      , c.date_created
      , c.date_approval_request
      , c.date_closed
      , u1.usrGivenName as user_name
      , c.muh_usrID
      , u2.usrGivenName as res_user_name

FROM cases AS c
JOIN users AS u1 ON c.usrID = u.usrID
JOIN users AS u2 ON c.res_usrID = u.usrID
```

Comment: Thank you very much that helped a lot and learned a new thing

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
         caseID
      ,c.date_created
      ,c.date_approval_request
      ,c.date_closed
      ,coalesce(u.usrGivenName, ru.usrGivenName, 'Not Available') 
      ,c.muh_usrID
  FROM cases AS c
  left JOIN users AS u ON c.usrID = u.usrID
  left JOIN users AS ru ON c.res_usrID = ru.usrID
```

Did not test, but you will get the idea.

Comment: Thank you  Parfait. Updated the answer per our comments.